# Integration against anti-symmetric kernel

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, fractional-calculus

Let $u\in C[0,T]$ and $\beta\in(0,1)$. Suppose that
$$
\int_0^x u(r)k(x,r)\,dr = 0,\quad \text{for all }x>0,
$$
where 
$$
k(x,r):= (x-r)^{-\beta}-r^{-\beta},\quad x>r>0.
$$
I want to prove that $u$ must be constant using the fact that  $k(x,\cdot)$ is anti-symmetric around $x/2$, for each $x>0$, in the sense that

$$
k(x,r) = -k(x,x-r).
$$

**Comment**: I can prove the statement by a maximum principle argument, after reducing the assumption to 
$$
\int_0^x (x-r)^{\beta-1}r^{-\beta}(u(r)-u(x))\,dr = 0,\quad x>0,
$$
by applying the [Riemann-Liouville integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral) $J^\beta_0f(x):=\int_0^x(x-r)^{\beta-1} f(z)$.